# Authorization required when checking-out bullet from kforge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to check out bullet from kforge with the following command.

> hg clone
> https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/bullet

Then it asks an authorization and spitted out a warning message.

> warning: kforge.ros.org certificate
> with fingerprint (my pc's mac-address)
> not verified (check hostfingerprints
> or web.cacerts config setting) http
> authorization required realm:
> kforge.ros.org Restricted Area user:

Mercurial version is 2.6.2, python 2.7.2 and running on Mac and the Ubuntu Linux.

Any recommendation would be appreciate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/84211/authorization-required-when-checking-out-bullet-from-kforge./) by [enddl22](https://answers.ros.org/users/194/enddl22/) on ROS Answers with karma: 177 on 2013-09-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Repos on kforge are being decommissioned this is the generic response for a repo which has gone away. http://ros-users.122217.n3.nabble.com/code-ros-org-and-kforge-ros-org-td4020313.html

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2